# XSL - Switch statement - help needed with syntax

Tags: xslt

Kind of a new XSL user and I'm trying to use a switch/choose syntax without much luck.  It seems to be defaulting every time to the 'otherwise' section.  Here is the code I'm attempting to use:

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@accountno=264835">
            <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@previousread * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@current * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:when>
                                                    
        <xsl:when test="@accountno=201631">
            <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@previousread * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@current * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:when>
                                                    
        <xsl:when test="@accountno=130159">
            <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@previousread * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@current * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:when>
                                                    
        <xsl:when test="@cycle=5">
            <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@previousread * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@current * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:when>
                                                    
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@previousread * 748 div 1000, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@current * 748 div 1000, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Am I not testing the variables correctly?  Something else?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Edit: more info

Just wondering if I'm testing the variables correctly in the choose/switch statement I guess...

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@accountno='264835'">
                   <!-- do something here if account matches 264835 -->
        </xsl:when>
                                                    
        <xsl:when test="@accountno='201631'">
                   <!-- do something here if account matches 201631-->                                                  
        </xsl:when>
                                                    
        <xsl:when test="@accountno='130159'">
                   <!-- do something here if account matches 130159 -->                                                 
        </xsl:when>
                                                    
        <xsl:when test="@cycle='5'">
                   <!-- do something here if cycle matches 5 -->
        </xsl:when>
                                                    
        <xsl:otherwise>
                   <!-- everything seems to be defaulting here -->                                                  
        </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

More Information:  I am not sure about context and that meaning, I assume you're correct that there is an error in there somewhere...  This is a little more of the code... hope it helps with context:

```
<xsl:for-each select="lineitems/servicelocation/group[@chargetype='METERED']/meter/meterread[string-length(@previousdate) &gt; 0]">
<xsl:sort select="concat(substring(@previousdate, 7, 4),substring(@previousdate, 1, 2),substring(@previousdate, 4, 2))" data-type="number"/>
<fo:table-row font-size="8pt">
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
             <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="../@number"/></fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
                                                    
<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@accountno='264835'">
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@previousread * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@current * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:when>
                                                        
        <xsl:when test="@accountno='201631'">
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@previousread * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@current * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:when>
                                                        
        <xsl:when test="@accountno='130159'">
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@previousread * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@current * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:when>
                                                        
        <xsl:when test="@cycle='5'">
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@previousread * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@current * .1, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:when>
                                                        
        <xsl:otherwise>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@previousread * .748, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="center"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@current * .748, '###,###,##0.000')"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
        </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<fo:table-cell padding="2pt"><fo:block text-align="right"><xsl:value-of select="@billingusage"/></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: You're testing correctly so the issue is probably context, but we can't tell for sure because your example is not reproducible.

Comment: It looks like the context is `meterread` (that's what's being selected by the `xsl:for-each`). Does that element have `accountno` and/or `cycle` attributes in your XML?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown us the context for this instruction, this probably means you haven't understood the importance of context, which probably means that you've got the context wrong. But of course this is pure guesswork.

Check that the context item (established by the instructions surrounding this `xsl:choose`) is the element you think it is.